# Is $\sqrt p - \lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor$, $p$ running over primes $1 \pmod 4$ , dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

A result I would like to know is if there are infinitely primes congruent to $1 \pmod 4$, with fractional part in an interval strictly contained in $\left(0,  \dfrac 1 4 \right)$. The title question seems to be true, and seems to be a natural way to prove the above.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090722/is-the-sequence-sqrtp-lfloor-sqrtp-rfloor-p-running-over-the-primes) the case for all primes is proven. However, as I am not a number theorist, I do not follow the argument too well. For my case, I would like a reference to an appropriate source, and maybe a proof which can be easily understood after finding the source.

Another way to look at it would be a generalisation of the result by Glyn Harman in *On the distribution of $\sqrt p$ modulo one* to this set of $p$. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find this either.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091129/276986). The proof works the same way as for the primes, showing that for $h \ne 0$ :  $$\sum_{n < x} \Lambda(n) e(h \sqrt{n}) = o(x), \qquad \sum_{n < x} \chi_4(n)\Lambda(n) e(h \sqrt{n}) = o(x)$$ (where $\chi_4(2n+1) = (-1)^n$ is the non-trivial character modulo $4$). Adding the two estimates, we have the result.

Comment: @user1952009 Do you have a reference for the second sum?

Comment: @i707107 No need, everything works the same way

Comment: @user1952009 I tried it, but didn't work nicely. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @i707107 Where are you stuck ? Did you look at the linked answer and Iwianec's book ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I tried it, I was struggling with an analogue of 13.39 for the twisted sum. But, I think I am slowly getting your hint.

Comment: @i707107 I can't write directly the equivalent formula for $\chi_4(n) \Lambda(n)$, but it will come in the same way from $$L(s,\chi_4) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_4(n) n^{-s},\qquad L'(s,\chi_4) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_4(n) n^{-s}\ln n, \qquad \frac{1}{L(s,\chi_4)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_4(n) \mu(n) n^{-s} ,\qquad\frac{L'}{L}(s,\chi_4) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_4(n) \Lambda(n) n^{-s}$$

Comment: I know that it is true now, which is the biggest relief. Unfortunately, I need this result to be clear to people (including me!) that do not have any knowledge of what you are using. That is why I was hoping for a paper with the result to reference. I'll continue the search, but thanks anyway!